# android studio "Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly"

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I don't understand the error says

> Error:Failed to create parent directory 'C:\Program
>   Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\daemon' when creating directory
>   'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\daemon\2.2.1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you had the project compile / work before? If so the issue is most likely your XML files having issues. Also try to make clean and make sure all of your dependencies are correct if you imported any.

You haven't given much info besides the error code about your project. Is this your first time using Android Studio? Did you update recently?